# How to fit 3D models in device screen when display it in 3d view

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

In my demo project(3D view). When model is display, Some models display large sized(out of screen) and some models are too small sized. What is best scale ratio to fit model in the device screen.

My code is..

```
     private fun createRenderAble() {
        ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(
            this, RenderableSource.builder()
                .setSource(this, Uri.parse(model?.modelUri), RenderableSource.SourceType.GLB)
                .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.CENTER)
                .build()
        ).setRegistryId(model?.modelUri)
         .build()
         .thenAccept { renderable ->
                hideProgress()
                addNodeToScene(renderable)
            }
            .exceptionally {
                showToast(it.localizedMessage)
                hideProgress()
                null
            }
}

 private fun addNodeToScenee(renderable: ModelRenderable?) {
    val tempNode = Node()
    tempNode.renderable = renderable

    val collisionShape: Box = tempNode.collisionShape as Box
   // var radius = 1f

  //  if (collisionShape.size.x > 2.0) {
 //       radius = 3f
  //  }
  //  if (collisionShape.size.y > 1.3) {
   //     radius = 2f
   // }

     radius=collisionShape.size.x
    val node = DragTransformableNode(radius, transformationSystem).apply {
        setParent(sceneView.scene)
        this.renderable = renderable
        select()
    }

    sceneView.scene.addChild(node)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control this by checking the size of your Renderable. 
Below is the code that will help you resolve the issue.
After setting renderable to node do the below.

```
        val collisionShape: Box = node.collisionShape as Box
        var radius = 1f
        if (collisionShape.size.x > 2.0) {
            radius = 3f
        }
        if (collisionShape.size.y > 1.3) {
            radius = 2f
        }
```

or

```
val collisionShape: Box = node.collisionShape as Box
 radius=collisionShape.size.x
```

Explanation: What I'm doing here is checking if renderable has width more than 2.0 meter I'm setting the radius of a camera to 3f. This will help us to accommodate the complete model into the screen. Same goes for the Height(`collisionShape.size.y`).

Comment: Hello @Nouman Ch     How to set camera radius??

Comment: @Olance https://github.com/chnouman/SceneView/blob/70abf79245c99fefe189e5672ce1d02324c083ab/app/src/main/java/com/nouman/sceneview/SceneViewActivity.kt#L135 this is the radius. Before passing it to constructor create simple node and set renderable then get collisionShape and calculate Radius.

Comment: Once radius calculated then you need to create another tranformable node and set the radius to it.

Comment: **Hello @Nouman Ch** still not working it. See the my updated code in question.

Comment: brother you need to debug the code and check on which value your models are getting out of screen. Not every model is going out so for those we need to set radius 1f.

Comment: Thanks brother after debugging my code i got best way in your suggestion to set radius

Comment: i simply add this line in above code

Comment: `radius=collisionShape.size.x`